# Aligning divs with border

Tags: html, css

I have 3 divs thats diplaying correctly but once I add border its alignment shorts or increases.

```
{% load static %}
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/css.css' %}">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="block1">
            Block1
        </div>
        <div id="block2">
            Block 2
        </div>

        <div id="block3">
            Block 3
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

css

```
html, body{
    height: 100%;
    width:100%;
}
#block1{
    height:10%;
    width:46%;
    text-align:center;
    float:left;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:green;
    border-width:20%;

}

#block2{
    height:90%;
    width:46%;
    float:right;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:green;
    border-width:2%;
}

#block3{
    height:80%;
    width:50%;
    float: left;

}
```

Comment: Have you set your blocks to have `box-sizing:border-box`? http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp

Comment: Just wait, someone will mention something about using w3school

Comment: I really dont understand the question - here is a fiddle for those who want to try out -> http://jsfiddle.net/L8LpJ/

Comment: @Huangism, :-) for a good reason though

Comment: maybe `outline` is what you want. it's like `border`, but doesn't take up space, so doesn't affect alignment